# CRUD application create working, but not update or delete

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

I tried getting the CRUD app to work from Tutorial Republic. I can create rows, but can’t read, update, or delete them.

I uploaded index, create, read, update, delete, config, and error.php. It loads index.php fine but when I try to update, read, or delete, all I get is a blank page. Please help. Here’s the code.

config.php

```
<?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret');
define('DB_NAME', 'demo');
 
/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

read.php

```
<?php
// Check existence of id parameter before processing further
if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
    // Include config file
    require_once "config.php";
    
    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id = ?";
    
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);
        
        // Set parameters
        $param_id = trim($_GET["id"]);
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set
                contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                
                // Retrieve individual field value
                $name = $row["name"];
                $address = $row["address"];
                $salary = $row["salary"];
            } else{
                // URL doesn't contain valid id parameter. Redirect to error page
                header("location: error.php");
                exit();
            }
            
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }
     
    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
} else{
    // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
    header("location: error.php");
    exit();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>View Record</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .wrapper{
            width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1 class="mt-5 mb-3">View Record</h1>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <p><b><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></b></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Address</label>
                        <p><b><?php echo $row["address"]; ?></b></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Salary</label>
                        <p><b><?php echo $row["salary"]; ?></b></p>
                    </div>
                    <p><a href="index.php" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

update.php

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$name = $address = $salary = "";
$name_err = $address_err = $salary_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])){
    // Get hidden input value
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    
    // Validate name
    $input_name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    if(empty($input_name)){
        $name_err = "Please enter a name.";
    } elseif(!filter_var($input_name, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
        $name_err = "Please enter a valid name.";
    } else{
        $name = $input_name;
    }
    
    // Validate address address
    $input_address = trim($_POST["address"]);
    if(empty($input_address)){
        $address_err = "Please enter an address.";     
    } else{
        $address = $input_address;
    }
    
    // Validate salary
    $input_salary = trim($_POST["salary"]);
    if(empty($input_salary)){
        $salary_err = "Please enter the salary amount.";     
    } elseif(!ctype_digit($input_salary)){
        $salary_err = "Please enter a positive integer value.";
    } else{
        $salary = $input_salary;
    }
    
    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($name_err) && empty($address_err) && empty($salary_err)){
        // Prepare an update statement
        $sql = "UPDATE employees SET name=?, address=?, salary=? WHERE id=?";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssi", $param_name, $param_address, $param_salary, $param_id);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_name = $name;
            $param_address = $address;
            $param_salary = $salary;
            $param_id = $id;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
         
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
} else{
    // Check existence of id parameter before processing further
    if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
        // Get URL parameter
        $id =  trim($_GET["id"]);
        
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id = ?";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_id = $id;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                    /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set
                    contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    
                    // Retrieve individual field value
                    $name = $row["name"];
                    $address = $row["address"];
                    $salary = $row["salary"];
                } else{
                    // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
                    header("location: error.php");
                    exit();
                }
                
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
        
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        
        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($link);
    }  else{
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: error.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Update Record</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .wrapper{
            width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2 class="mt-5">Update Record</h2>
                    <p>Please edit the input values and submit to update the employee record.</p>
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($name_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $name_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Address</label>
                            <textarea name="address" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($address_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $address; ?></textarea>
                            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $address_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Salary</label>
                            <input type="text" name="salary" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($salary_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $salary; ?>">
                            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $salary_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                        <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-secondary ml-2">Cancel</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
// Process delete operation after confirmation
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])){
    // Include config file
    require_once "config.php";
    
    // Prepare a delete statement
    $sql = "DELETE FROM employees WHERE id = ?";
    
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);
        
        // Set parameters
        $param_id = trim($_POST["id"]);
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Records deleted successfully. Redirect to landing page
            header("location: index.php");
            exit();
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }
     
    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
} else{
    // Check existence of id parameter
    if(empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: error.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Delete Record</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .wrapper{
            width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2 class="mt-5 mb-3">Delete Record</h2>
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo trim($_GET["id"]); ?>"/>
                            <p>Are you sure you want to delete this employee record?</p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="submit" value="Yes" class="btn btn-danger">
                                <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-secondary">No</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

error.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Error</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .wrapper{
            width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2 class="mt-5 mb-3">Invalid Request</h2>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry, you've made an invalid request. Please <a href="index.php" class="alert-link">go back</a> and try again.</div>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's too much code to sort through. Please narrow it down to only the relevant sections. See [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Also, it's not a good idea to use the `root` account. Create a separate login for the web application an assign the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Beyond what SOS said, turn on PHP and MySQL error reporting, and skip JavaScript and jQuery _completely_ until you understand HTML, HTTP, MySQL and PHP